# Set a style color based on an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I want to set the Background color of an object's style, to be the color of the Window Foreground. So.... how to get the color of one object and use it as the value in a style?

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="????Window Foreground Color????" />
```

I've tried different binding combinations, but none of them have worked yet. In code-behind this value would be *this.Foreground*, but in XAML style?

Comment: How about showing the bindings you tried and the [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) you got?

Comment: It didn't give any errors, except for not having any effect. As long as syntax was okay.

Comment: You don't know what binding errors are, do you? How about clicking the link i provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest way would be to give you parent Window a name and use that in binding. Something like this (if you named your window "Root"):

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Foreground}" />
```

Comment: That worked :) (I may have even tried that but had name/class-name mixed up.)